# Stop jQuery .data() from converting

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to stop the .data() function from converting the data to another type?

For example, with the HTML `<div data-code-name="007">Bond, James</div>`

`$("div").data("codeName")` returns 7 instead of "007"

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dMHS4/

**Update:** I just noticed in the fiddle that if you change to jQuery 1.8.2 it **does not** convert. http://jsfiddle.net/dMHS4/2/

**Update:** [Has jQuery 1.8 changed how .data() returns the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625742/has-jquery-1-8-changed-how-data-returns-the-value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `.attr()` instead of `.data()`:

```
$("div").attr("data-code-name")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dMHS4/1/

---

Taken from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise
>   it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string
>   without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method

Comment: +1. This is from official `data` doc: `Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method`

Comment: Yeah, but see my update. jQuery 1.7.2 does the conversion, 1.8.2 does not. Has the documented functionality changed with the new version?