# Has jQuery 1.8 changed how .data() returns the value?

Tags: jquery

Related question: [Stop jQuery .data() from converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622812/stop-jquery-data-from-converting)

According to the documentation for `.data()`:

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise
>   it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string
>   without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method

This is true for jQuery 1.7.2, but 1.8.2 does not do the conversion. Is this the new expected behavior?

For example, with the HTML `<div data-code-name="007">Bond, James</div>`

jQuery v1.7.2
`$("div").data("codeName")` returns 7
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dMHS4/

jQuery v1.8.2
`$("div").data("codeName")` returns "007"
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dMHS4/2/

Comment: jQuery always attempts to do a conversion. The change is in how far it goes. I think it's reasonable to assume that a number that begins with zero shouldn't be automatically converted to a number.

Comment: I would look at the release notes for the various versions in question, example 1.8.1: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this answers your question

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7579

They also have a test fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dmethvin/8SsWK/

And it shows that if converting to a number changed it from say 1.0 to 1, then it now is treated as a string, instead of a number.  You can see this difference if you run there tests in 1.7.2 vs 1.8.2

Comment: The comments on the ticket were helpful, and the test fiddle is an excellent example. Thanks!